# KQL KeywordQuery - Unable to display managed properties

Tags: c#, sharepoint, keywordquery

I am trying to build a KQL Query using KeywordQuery.
I have some managed properties columns that I want to display in the result table but it's not working for me.

here is the code:

```
            oKeywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(oSite);
            oKeywordQuery.SelectProperties.Clear();
            oKeywordQuery.QueryText = sQuery;
            oKeywordQuery.KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords;

            oKeywordQuery.StartRow = 0;
            oKeywordQuery.RowLimit = 500;
            oKeywordQuery.EnableNicknames = true;
            oKeywordQuery.EnablePhonetic = true;
            oKeywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;


            oKeywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("IsDocument"); //This one as a test I was able to display but no managed properties
            foreach (string sDisplayField in oDisplayFields)
            {
                oKeywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add(sDisplayField);
            }

                oSearchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
                oResultTableColl = oSearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(oKeywordQuery);
                var oResultTable = oResultTableColl.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);

                oRTable = oResultTable.FirstOrDefault();
```

I am able to get results but no managed properties columns are shown.
What seems to be the problem?

Comment: UPDATE: Some managed properties columns I am able to show but some are still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured out that I had WHITE SPACES in the properties string.
For example:

```
     oKeywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add(" MyPropTitle ");
```

Should be:

```
    oKeywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("MyPropTitle");
```